# Using linear actuator in the limited space

Tags: actuator

What is most effective way to apply linear actuator to move a lift within a small sized space?

I.e. for example, for 14", which is total 820mm, to move a 330 mm lift in 740mm height box (width and depth are not limited)?

[image: linear actuator]

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the distance moved using a lever, but the input force needed increases...